# Can a virtual address be remapped to different physical addresses while process is running?

Tags: virtual-memory

Is it theoretically possible and does any OS actually use it? If yes, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens all the time. The OS may need the physical memory in question so it unmaps and later remaps.